# how can I connect 2 wired internet into one?

Tags: internet, ethernet, modem, adsl, broadband

I have 2 wired internet connections one is free offered by my apartment management and other one is paid by office. They both are broadband 2mbps and 4mbps respectively. One is dynamic IP address internet and I have to login into ISP website first before using internet and other use PPPoE which has its username and password stored in modem. Now my question is I want to combine both of them so that I can get great download and upload speed. Both connections have different modems. Is there anyway so that I can combine them? Some sort of 3rd router or use other hardware devices like raspberry pi?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. There is a feature of windows is Bridge connection. 
You can make a bridge connection. Or alternatively you can use software like Speedify (Previously known as Connectify Dispatch).

Speedify will ease your pain otherwise you may need to configure your internet connection.

Comment: It will become specific for windows only how will I use wifi?

Comment: ok now you tell me from which device you want to accumulate internet. 1 is cable I mean Lan and 2nd is wifi router. If so then you can join or merge them to boost up the internet. but you can use it on you computer but you can't make it now wifi hotspot because you are using your wifi mate.

Comment: my both LAN connections has adsl modem + router so I have 2 modem + wifi.

I want both connection to bridge so that I can use both on wifi and my pc
If required I can buy another device,

Comment: Now tell me how you will make the connection in your computer at a time. Make them connect at a time then use the software to merge them all. If you have two lan I mean broadband you need two Lan port for input. If you have 1 lan port then you need 1 wifi. If you have 2 lan port and one wifi make 3 of them connect and merge them with software.